# What is the result set returned as?

Tags: sql, sql-server

So I have this stored procedure that queries a table and return a result set, but I am using that result set as a param for a store procedure that I execute inside my store procedure.

```
SELECT employeeID FROM employeeList where LastName = 'Zhou'
..... Some stuff .....
exec my_store_proc @employeeID = 'a comma separated string of employee ID'
```

Where `my_store_proc` has a param `@employeeID AS VARCHAR(8000) = '',`. I know I can use a cursor to traverse the result set and concatenate them into a comma separated string. But I was wondering **what is the result set returned from the select statement alone, does it have a data type?** I was hoping the answer would be a comma separated string already so that I can just set `employeeID = employeeID`. But my gut feeling says no.

Comment: What does the `exec` or icky-denormalized-join have to do with the question and/or SELECT result? The type of `employeeID` is the type of `employeeID` column. This is the [only] typing information the SELECT has, which is why I asked why the other information is supposed to be relevant.

Comment: Are you talking about [Table-Valued parameters](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb510489.aspx)?

Comment: What is it with all of the comma separated strings?

Comment: @user2864740 it to privide context into what I am trying to do

Comment: @valverij No what I mean is what is the result set?

Comment: @Zane Not sure, it's that just what the store procedure wants. These aren't my code I am just finishing up some stuff for other when they are on vacation

Comment: @JackThor The result-set is exactly as if you typed `SELECT employeeID ..` in SSMS.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As it is your SELECT produces a result-set, which is techically a table. But you can collect result of this SELECT into a comma separated Varchar:

```
DECLARE @sResult VARCHAR(8000)
SET @sResult = ''

SELECT @sResult = @sResult + ',' + CAST(employeeID as varchar(10)) 
FROM employeeList where LastName = 'Zhou'

SET @sResult = STUFF(@sResult,1,1,'')
```

Basically you declare a varchar variable then use a form of SELECT that collects values into a single string (assuming employeeID is an INT hence CAST)

Last line removes leading comma.

After that you can make a call

```
exec my_store_proc @employeeID = @sResult
```

Comment: Nice I did not know you could do that. And the result set is a table. Got it :)